# If the distance from Earth to the Sun was filled with air, how loud would the sun be?

Tags: the-sun, earth, sound

Based on this question: [If there was air between the Sun and Earth, how warm would we get?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/19864/if-there-was-air-between-the-sun-and-earth-how-warm-would-we-get)

Many sources state that if sound wasn't limited by matter, we would hear the Sun at around 100dB constantly, but assuming sound was traveling in the same circumstances as Earth's ground atmosphere, could the Sun still be heard?

Comment: This question isn't really about astronomy, and we don't normally answer impossible hypothetical questions here. But it has been asked on our sister site: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/107195/123208